# How to find the starting position of a specific word in a sentence in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Suppose a sentence is "How is Kunal", how to find the starting position of word Kunal in that sentence using RPGLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what you've tried..

But seems that [%SCAN()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/bbscan.htm) would work

```
dcl-s myString varchar(50);
dcl-s posFound int(5);
 
myString = 'How is Kunal';
pos = %scan('Kunal':myString);
if pos > 0;
  //found it 
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a word, you want to find the text only when preceded by whitespace or start of string. Or, maybe even when preceded by a non word character. The sql regular expression function `regexp_instr` will do that.

```
d text            s            256a   varying
d i5              s              5i 0
d fx              s             10i 0

 /free
  // use capture groups to return position of the search text, only when preceded
  // by whitespace or start of string.

  // sql function regexp_instr returns either the start position of the
  // search text. Or the position after that pattern.

  // The 7th parameter specifies which capture group to return the match position of.

      text        = 'How is Kunal' ;
      exec sql
      set         :fx :i5 = regexp_instr( :text, '(^|\s+)(Kunal)', 1, 1,
                                          0, '', 2 ) ;
```